# how to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 in php, issue?

Tags: php, math

i have an small issue with the way this problem is resolved.

some would say: `println((0 /: ((0 until 1000).filter(x => x % 3 == 0 || x % 5 == 0))) (_+_))` is the solution witch adds to `233168`

my way was to do:

```
$maxnumber = 1000; 
for ($i = 3; $i < $maxnumber; $i += 3) 
{ 
         $t += $i; 
         echo $i.',';
}  
echo '<br>';
for ($j = 5; $j < $maxnumber; $j += 5) 
{ 
    $d += $j; 
    echo $j.',';
}  

echo '<br>';
echo $t;
echo '<br>';
echo $d;
echo '<br>';
echo $t+$d;
```

this will give me :

```
3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120,123,126,129,132,135,138,141,144,147,150,153,156,159,162,165,168,171,174,177,180,183,186,189,192,195,198,201,204,207,210,213,216,219,222,225,228,231,234,237,240,243,246,249,252,255,258,261,264,267,270,273,276,279,282,285,288,291,294,297,300,303,306,309,312,315,318,321,324,327,330,333,336,339,342,345,348,351,354,357,360,363,366,369,372,375,378,381,384,387,390,393,396,399,402,405,408,411,414,417,420,423,426,429,432,435,438,441,444,447,450,453,456,459,462,465,468,471,474,477,480,483,486,489,492,495,498,501,504,507,510,513,516,519,522,525,528,531,534,537,540,543,546,549,552,555,558,561,564,567,570,573,576,579,582,585,588,591,594,597,600,603,606,609,612,615,618,621,624,627,630,633,636,639,642,645,648,651,654,657,660,663,666,669,672,675,678,681,684,687,690,693,696,699,702,705,708,711,714,717,720,723,726,729,732,735,738,741,744,747,750,753,756,759,762,765,768,771,774,777,780,783,786,789,792,795,798,801,804,807,810,813,816,819,822,825,828,831,834,837,840,843,846,849,852,855,858,861,864,867,870,873,876,879,882,885,888,891,894,897,900,903,906,909,912,915,918,921,924,927,930,933,936,939,942,945,948,951,954,957,960,963,966,969,972,975,978,981,984,987,990,993,996,999

5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100,105,110,115,120,125,130,135,140,145,150,155,160,165,170,175,180,185,190,195,200,205,210,215,220,225,230,235,240,245,250,255,260,265,270,275,280,285,290,295,300,305,310,315,320,325,330,335,340,345,350,355,360,365,370,375,380,385,390,395,400,405,410,415,420,425,430,435,440,445,450,455,460,465,470,475,480,485,490,495,500,505,510,515,520,525,530,535,540,545,550,555,560,565,570,575,580,585,590,595,600,605,610,615,620,625,630,635,640,645,650,655,660,665,670,675,680,685,690,695,700,705,710,715,720,725,730,735,740,745,750,755,760,765,770,775,780,785,790,795,800,805,810,815,820,825,830,835,840,845,850,855,860,865,870,875,880,885,890,895,900,905,910,915,920,925,930,935,940,945,950,955,960,965,970,975,980,985,990,995

$t - 166833
$d - 99500
```

and total:
    266333

why am i wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some numbers are multiples of both 3 and 5. (Your algorithm adds these numbers to the total twice.)

Answer (score 4):

Because 6 * 5 == 30 and 10 * 3 == 30, you're adding the some numbers up twice.

```
$sum = 0;
$i = 0;
foreach(range(0, 999) as $i) {
    if($i % 3 == 0 || $i % 5 == 0) $sum += $i;
}
```

Comment: This is the ideal way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Because you double-count numbers that are multiple of both 3 and 5, i.e. multiples of 15.

You can account for this naively by subtracting all multiples of 15.

```
for ($j = 15; $j < $maxnumber; $j += 15) 
{ 
    $e += $j; 
    echo $j.',';
}  
$total = $total - $d;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, if it is 15, you will add the number twice.

Try this:

```
$t = 0;
$d = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $maxnumber; $i++){
    if ($i % 3 == 0)
        $t+= $i;
    else if ($i % 5 == 0)
        $d += $i;
}

echo $t.'<br>'.$d;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your code, if a number is a multiple of 3 and 5, it is added twice. Take 15 for example. It's in your list of multiples of 3 and in the list of multiples of 5. Is this the behaviour you want?

Answer (score 1):

One of the best approach to this solution (to achieve optimum time complexity), run an Arithmetic Progression series and find the number of terms in all series by using AP formula: **T=a+(n-1)d**, then find sum by : **S=n/2[2*a+(n-1)d]**

- where : a=first term ,n=no. of term , d=common deference, T=nth term

The code solution below has been implemented to suit the question above - so the values 3 and 5 are hard-coded. However, the function can modified such that values are passed in as variable parameters.

```
function solution($number){

  $val1 = 3;
  $val2 = 5;
  $common_term = $val1 * $val2;

  $sum_of_terms1 = calculateSumofMulitples($val1,$number);
  $sum_of_terms2 = calculateSumofMulitples($val2,$number);
  $sum_of_cterms = calculateSumofMulitples($common_term,$number);

  $final_result = $sum_of_terms1 + $sum_of_terms2 - $sum_of_cterms;

  return $final_result;
}

function calculateSumofMulitples($val, $number)
{
    //first, we begin by running an aithmetic prograssion for $val up to $number say N to get the no of terms [using T=a +(n-1)d]
    $no_of_terms =   (int) ($number / $val);
    if($number % $val == 0) $no_of_terms = (int) ( ($number-1)/$val ); //since we are computing for a no of terms below N and not up to/exactly/up to N. if N divides val with no remainder, use no of terms = (N-1)/val 

    //second, we compute the sum of terms [using Sn = n/2[2a + (n-1)d]
    $sum_of_terms = ($no_of_terms * 0.5) * ( (2*$val)  + ($no_of_terms - 1) * $val );

    // sum of multiples 
    return $sum_of_terms;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a single loop checking whether the number is multiple of 3 OR 5:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $maxnumber; $i++) 
{
 if($i%3 || $i%5){
         $t += $i; 
         echo $i.',';}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the original code is not including numbers which are multiples of both 3 and 5 in the total: if the test for multiple of 3 matches, it takes that and goes on.
If you total the multiples of 15 up to 1000, you get 33165, which is exactly the difference between your total, 266333, and the original total, 233168.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to the question:

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
$arr = [];
for($i = 1; $i < 1000; $i++){
if((int)$i % 3 === 0 || (int)$i % 5 === 0)
   {
    $sum += $i;
    array_push($arr,$i);
    }   
}
echo $sum;
echo '<br>';
print_r($arr);//Displays the values meeting the criteria as an array of values
```